# Как открыть контроллер с помощь UIPreviewAction?

Tags: iphone, swift

Я хочу реализовать поддержку 3D touch, когда контроллер находиться в режиме Peek, я добавил UIPreviewAction, и там есть кнопка показать, я пытался в блоке данного UIPreviewAction сделать множество различных вариантов, чтобы открыть полностью контроллер, но ни один не сработал. Как я могу это сделать?

```
override func previewActionItems() -> [UIPreviewActionItem] {
    let showAction = UIPreviewAction(title: "Показать", style: .Default) { [weak self] (action: UIPreviewAction, vc: UIViewController) -> Void in
        guard let weakSelf = self else {
            return;
        }

        if let _pop = weakSelf.pop {
            _pop()
        }
    }

    return [showAction]
}
```

Comment: предположу, что `showViewController(previewViewController, sender: self)`

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko нет, не сработало, пробовал в самом начаое

Comment: а у вас там navigationController есть? или просто один контроллер root и все?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko да есть navigationController, проблема в том, что контроллер уже показан в режиме peek, если нажать сильнее то он откроется во весь экран, но по заданию нужно, что бы можно было открыть контроллер с кнопки

Comment: а если создать другую копию того же контроллера и показать ее?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko я думаю это не очень хороший подход. Это уже как костыль

Comment: вы посмотрите сработает ли, а там можно подумать над чем то покрасивее

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko хорошо, в скором времени посмотрю

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko я сделал с помощью центра уведомлений, но думаю это костыль